# Analysis of Variance table

Tags: statistics

I am trying to fill out an analysis of variance table with the following data given

[image]

I need to fill out the table below with what I am given but I do not have all the data needed so I cannot use an anova() function in R. I am stuck and would like some help so I can fill out the table. thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: You'll have to look in a textbook for the one-way (unbalanced) ANOVA formulas. Start with DFs, which should be very easy. Then maybe MS(Within), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intent of this exercise is worthwhile. Even if you typically
use software to do your one-way ANOVAs, it is a good idea to
know what the software is computing and why.

However, you can *cheat the intent of the exercise* by reconstructing the the data in the three levels of the factor from the sample sizes, means, and standard deviations given. Knowing how to do this
is sometimes useful in debugging programs and (as here) in using R to
do certain procedures from summarized data.

**Reconstruction from standard normal samples,** adjusted to
have *sample* means exactly 0 and SDs exactly 1. [This method assumes normal data.]

```
set.seed(503)
z1 = rnorm(98)
z1 = (z1-mean(z1))/sd(z1)  # adjust
mean(z1); sd(z1)
[1] -8.319592e-19
[1] 1
x1 = 1.39*z1 + .49
mean(x1); sd(x1)          # reconstruct
[1] 0.49
[1] 1.39

z2 = rnorm(94)
z2 = (z2-mean(z2))/sd(z2)
mean(z1); sd(z1)
[1] -8.319592e-19
[1] 1
x2 = 1.39*z2 - .56
mean(x2); sd(x2)
[1] -0.56
[1] 1.39

z3 = rnorm(98)
z3 = (z3-mean(z3))/sd(z3)
mean(z3); sd(z3)
[1] -5.96975e-18
[1] 1
x3 = 1.05*z3 + .04
mean(x3); sd(x3)
[1] 0.04
[1] 1.05
```

**Use R to make ANOVA table:**

```
x = c(x1,x2,x3)
g = as.factor(rep(1:3, c(98,94,98)))  # g MUST be 'factor'

anova(lm(x~g))

Analysis of Variance Table

Response: x
           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
g           2  53.16 26.5817  16.093 2.375e-07 ***
Residuals 287 474.04  1.6517                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Alternatively:

```
aov(x ~ g)
Call:
   aov(formula = x ~ g)

Terms:
                       g Residuals
Sum of Squares   53.1633  474.0415
Deg. of Freedom        2       287

Residual standard error: 1.28519  # square to get MS(Res)
Estimated effects may be unbalanced
```